# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'title' of 'tracks[trackIndex]' as it is undefined - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-hooks

I want to set the track index to the queue number of song but with `setTrackIndex` I'm getting a type error and I can't manipulate `trackIndex` directly because it's a constant variable. is there any way I can do what i do. this is what I'm trying but getting the error.

```
const [trackIndex, setTrackIndex] = useState(0)
const { title, artist, image, audioSrc } = tracks[trackIndex]
var i = 0
```

```
{tracks.map(track => {
  i++
  return (
    <div className="song-details-artwork queue-next">
        <div className="art">
            <img style={{ width: "100%" }} src={track["image"]} alt="" />
        </div>
        <div onClick={() => {setTrackIndex(i)} className="song-names">
              <div className="queue-song-name">{track["title"]}</div>
              <div className="queue-song-name">{track["artist"]}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
})}
```

Comment: You need to handle `undefined` case. One way to do that might be: `const { title, artist, image, audioSrc } = tracks[trackIndex] ?? {}`

Comment: yeah but now it doesn't set the track index and return empty.

Comment: The second parameter to `.map()` is the index of the element. No need to maintain a separate index. I'd hazard a guess that it somehow fails because the index you maintain is wrong. Because it doesn't make sense to map over an array and an index that should be there to return nothing from the array.

Comment: Can you show us data in `tracks`? And, why is `tracks[trackIndex]` `undefined` in the first place?

Comment: Ah, in fact this *is* wrong because you increment the index before you use it. So you map over a zero-based array and use one-based indexes for it. The final one would be out of bounds, because it'd be one over the length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments mention, you should handle the `undefined` case (elsewhere, not in the component where you are doing the render), i.e., when your `tracks` is `undefined` or `null`.

While this code can handle an empty array... it would just show nothing, so it would be great to have some debugging available with you.

Your code can be slightly improved to:

```
{tracks.map((track,index)=> (
   <div className="song-details-artwork queue-next">
     <div className="art">
       <img style={{ width: "100%" }} src={track["image"]} alt="" />
     </div>
     <div onClick={() => {setTrackIndex(index)} className="song-names">
        <div className="queue-song-name">{track["title"]}</div>
        <div className="queue-song-name">{track["artist"]}</div>
     </div>
   </div>))}
```

Comment: "*As the comments mention, you should handle the undefined case*" I disagree. It makes no logical sense to handle it. Because it means that you have a track than when used, returns nothing. That's a bug. Making the track that doesn't work **not** throw an error hides the bug. Doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: It doesn't need to be handled in this component, but it needs to be handled somewhere else, apologies for being vague, will make the correction. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes. OP should use `map`'s `index` instead of their `i` (in the question).